# How to install Battle.net through Steam?

Tags: wine, steam, games

I don't even know if it is possible, I saw it nowhere.

My guess is that Linux Steam has a powerful cross-platform software part called Proton able to run any Windows software, most of the time better than Wine.

So instead of using Lutris, why not using Steam?

Comment: Are you running into specific issues with Battle.net on Lutris?

Comment: No, just that the Debian 11 packages are not up to date (so it's missing Battle.net in my list in Lutris), and a better version is still absent from the backports. Then no Lutris option for me right now. And it's always good to have alternatives.

Comment: You’re in luck, [Lutris has just been backported to Debian 11](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1431803/accepted-lutris-0512-1bpo111-source-all-into-bullseye-backports/), you can [install it from there](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/).